# How to select a specific row based on another row from same table

Tags: sql-server, duplication

I have a table with duplicated rows, I want to select only one row out of many that has a field populated in it.

Example:

```
  +--------+------+---------------+
  |  id    | col1 |     col2      |
  +--------+------+---------------+
  | 111111 |    9 | Not Specified |
  | 111111 |    1 | Green         |
  | 222222 |    9 | Not Specified |
  | 333333 |    1 | Blue          |
  | 444444 |    9 | Not Specified |
  | 444444 |    2 | Undisclosed   |
  +--------+------+---------------+
```

Output:

```
+--------+------+---------------+
|  id    | col1 |     col2      |
+--------+------+---------------+
| 111111 |    1 | Green         |
| 222222 |    9 | Not Specified |
| 333333 |    1 | Blue          |
| 444444 |    2 | Undisclosed   |
+--------+------+---------------+
```

Comment: Is there any reason to delete the first duplicated?

Comment: Yes, once I have the values for col1, col2 for the specific id I no longer need the id with the unspecified information and i would like to delete it.

Comment: I mean, does it matter if I delete first or last duplicated?

Comment: You may want to add some explanation of why the expected result looks like it does.

Comment: @user119472 If you're going to use an unregistered (cookie-based) account, you'll need to access the site from the same device and browser each time to retain control of your question. Otherwise, [register](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account), then ask for your [accounts to be merged](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Answer (score 1):

Add a ROW_NUMBER(), and select all records where row_number = 1.

```
with dupli as
(
    select id, col1, col2, row_number() over (partition by id order by col1) rn
    from @dup
)
select     d1.*
from       @dup d1
inner join dupli d2
on         d1.id = d2.id
and        d1.col1 = d2.col1
and        d2.rn = 1;

|id    |col1|col2         |
|:-----|---:|:------------|
|111111|   1|Green        |
|222222|   9|Not Specified|
|333333|   1|Blue         |
|444444|   2|Undisclosed  |
```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=796904c6dc41748d0facd2c0f5145e63)*

Answer (score 1):

Use row_number()

```
select id, col1, col2 
from ( select id, col1, col2
            , row_number() over (partition by id order by col1) rn
       from table 
     ) tt 
where rn = 1
```